# Custom Button using styled components typescript

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Im trying to create a custom button component which accepts icon as a prop 'icon', we are using style-components and styled system for utility styling. While rendering the component, im getting a typescript overload error. Please refer the component code:

```
import React, { FC, ReactNode } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import {
  layout,
  space,
  variant,
  fontSize,
  border,
  shadow,
  LayoutProps,
  SpaceProps,
  FontSizeProps,
  BorderProps,
  ShadowProps,
  flexbox,
  FlexboxProps,
  position,
  PositionProps,
} from "styled-system";

export interface IconButtonProps
  extends LayoutProps,
    SpaceProps,
    FontSizeProps,
    BorderProps,
    ShadowProps,
    FlexboxProps,
    PositionProps,
    Omit<React.HTMLProps<HTMLElement>, "color" | "height" | "size" | "width" | "as"> {
  children: any;
  variant: "primary" | "secondary";
  icon: ReactNode;
}

const IconButtonContainer = styled.button<IconButtonProps>`
  border-radius: ${({ theme }) => theme.space["spacing-200"]};
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: ${({ theme }) => theme.fontSizes["font-24"]};
  padding: "8px";
  ${variant({
    variants: {
      primary: {
        color: "neutral.0",
        backgroundColor: "blue.400",
        border: "1px solid",
        borderColor: "blue.400",
        "&:hover": {
          border: "1px solid",
          borderColor: "blue.300",
          backgroundColor: "blue.300",
        },
        "&:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active": {
          border: "1px solid",
          borderColor: "blue.500",
          backgroundColor: "blue.500",
        },
        "&:disabled": {
          opacity: ".6",
          color: "neutral.60",
          border: "1px solid",
          borderColor: "neutral.50",
          backgroundColor: "neutral.20",
          cursor: "default",
        },
      },
      secondary: {
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        border: "0",
        "&:hover": {
          border: "1px solid",
          backgroundColor: "blue.50",
        },
        "&:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active": {
          border: "1px solid",
          backgroundColor: "blue.50",
        },
        "&:disabled": {
          border: "0",
          opacity: ".6",
          cursor: "default",
        },
      },
    },
  })}
  ${variant({
    prop: "size",
    variants: {
      medium: {
        fontWeight: "semibold",
        height: "24px",
      },
    },
  })}

  ${space} ${fontSize} ${border} ${layout} ${shadow} ${flexbox} ${position};
`;

export const IconButton = (props: IconButtonProps) => {
  return <IconButtonContainer {...props}>{props.icon}</IconButtonContainer>;
};
```

[image: Error in red line]
And the error is :

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { cite?: string | undefined; data?: string | undefined; form?: string | undefined; label?: string | undefined; p?: ResponsiveValue<string | number | symbol, Required<Theme>> | undefined; ... 445 more ...; left?: ResponsiveValue<...> | undefined; } & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
> Type '{ children: ReactNode; variant: "primary" | "secondary"; icon: ReactNode; width?: ResponsiveValue<Width, Required<Theme>> | undefined; ... 445 more ...; wrap?: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ cite?: string | undefined; data?: string | undefined; form?: string | undefined; label?: string | undefined; p?: ResponsiveValue<string | number | symbol, Required<Theme>> | undefined; ... 445 more ...; left?: ResponsiveValue<...> | undefined; }'.
> Types of property 'ref' are incompatible.
> Type 'LegacyRef | undefined' is not assignable to type '((((instance: HTMLButtonElement | null) => void) | RefObject) & (string | ((instance: HTMLElement | null) => void) | RefObject<...>)) | null | undefined'.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '((((instance: HTMLButtonElement | null) => void) | RefObject) & (string | ((instance: HTMLElement | null) => void) | RefObject<...>)) | null | undefined'.
> Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"button", any, IconButtonProps, never, "button", "button">): ReactElement<StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"button", any, IconButtonProps, never, "button", "button">, string | JSXElementConstructor<...>>', gave the following error.
> Type '{ children: ReactNode; variant: "primary" | "secondary"; icon: ReactNode; width?: ResponsiveValue<Width, Required<Theme>> | undefined; ... 445 more ...; wrap?: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ cite?: string | undefined; data?: string | undefined; form?: string | undefined; label?: string | undefined; p?: ResponsiveValue<string | number | symbol, Required<Theme>> | undefined; ... 445 more ...; left?: ResponsiveValue<...> | undefined; }'.
> Types of property 'ref' are incompatible.
> Type 'LegacyRef | undefined' is not assignable to type '((((instance: HTMLButtonElement | null) => void) | RefObject) & (string | ((instance: HTMLElement | null) => void) | RefObject<...>)) | null | undefined'.ts(2769)
> const IconButtonContainer: StyledComponent<"button", any, IconButtonProps, never>

Can someone please help, im a new to typescript and its throwing me more errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try change this line:

```
Omit<React.HTMLProps<HTMLElement>, "color" | "height" | "size" | "width" | "as">
```

```
Omit<React.HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement>, "color" | "height" | "size" | "width" | "as">
```

If this doesn't work you might have a problem, maybe you ll need to specify type of IconButton, because it takes by default type `any`

```
export const IconButton: FC<IconButtonProps> = ({ icon, ...props }) => {
```

If you still got a problem maybe it's better to create a new type for the native button props.

Hope my answer will help you.

Comment: Hi ,thanks for the help but  im still getting the error